# jQuery html(), loading an img tag into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do the following:

```
var foo = '<p><img src="tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain /></p>';
$("#outputdiv").html(foo);
```

This is what shows up in outputdiv: `<p></p>`

Is there some reason that this shouldn't work? I'm running out of ideas. I've also tried using innerHTML, to no avail.

Comment: `src="tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain"` - missing `"` at the end?

Comment: your missing a `"` on the `img src` tag, but not sure if that's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid (missing quote).

Replace

```
var foo = '<p><img src="tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain /></p>';
```

with

```
var foo = '<p><img src="tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain" /></p>';
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing hahah. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should replace

```
var foo = '<p><img src="tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain /></p>';
```

with

```
var foo = "<p><img src='tracking.pixel.outside.my.domain' /></p>";
```

I think simple quotes must be inside double quotes.

Comment: You can definitely do it either way but you'll notice that you fixed my typo too hah.

Comment: Most languages which do not have a special `char` datatype (such a C) allow `"` and `'` to be used for string quoting.